# Limit ip access by creating a new browser?

Tags: security, browser

i don't know if this is the best approach, but here is it:
I've made a system in django and only want the users in a lab to be able to access it, so they can't go to other web pages(it's a program that the students can answer some tests).

I've read that doing the proxy stuff to limit the IP is very easily bypassed(since all the students from IT).
Them I read somewhere that you can create your own "Chrome" or firefox browser.
And it made me wander if I can make a browser that can only access one domain (in this case my project domain). This way it would be more invisible to the users what's going on.

But I can't find any good references to do this, and don't know if this is a complicated stuff.
Is it necessary to change the code of an existing browser? or can I just create a extension for it?

Comment: This is very unclear.  Are these users using their own computer?  Do you just want to limit access to the local network?  Are they logging in with a username/password?

Comment: How are you going to stop them from using their own browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not do your test on a fixed private network where the only IP address that the connected machines can see is the one with the test. Any requests to external pages will fail because the Internet won't be reachable.

Editing a browser is possible, but is likely that it will be simulteniously excessive for what you want and insufficient to stop users from getting content that you don't want them to have.